# find and delete command in linux returning exit status 1 after deleting files

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on a linux script in which i have to delete the directories which are created before 7days. I have found a command which does the same. Below is the command

```
find /some/thing/ -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But when i am checking the exit status of the command using `echo $?` it is returning 1 even after deleting the files from the location.

To create a directory with old time stamp i am using the below set of commands. Creates a folder and then modified date to 2018-05-10

```
mkdir sample
touch -t 1805100000.00 sample
```

Comment: I don't think that command creates a directory.

Comment: my bad create a directory and then use this command to change the modified date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man find says

> find  exits  with  status  0  if all files are processed successfully,
>   greater than 0 if errors occur.   This is deliberately a very broad
>   description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely
>   on the correctness of the results of find.

That means if at least one directory was not possible to delete then the find returns something else than 1. If there is a directory structure like

```
/some/thing/subdir
/some/thing/subdir/subsubdir
```

and both subsdirs are eligible to delete then find may delete the `/some/thing/subdir` first and then delete of the `/some/thing/subdir/subsubdir` fails because it does not exist anymore.

---

EDIT

The original answer contains explanation why but does not contain a proposal how to solve it. Deleep's comment proposed to use the `-depth` parameter to force find process each directory's contents before the directory itself. Indeed it works:

```
find /some/thing/ -type d -mtime +7 -depth -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Hi @zaboj. Thanks for the explanation. what you have pointed out seems to be the issue. As a workaround i am using `-depth`  as an argument in the find command to list the directories in the reverse order. This has resolved the issue. Thank you so much for quickly pointing to the problem

Comment: I will be happy to accept your answer if you can add some details about the `-depth` work around to over come the problem. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the possible causes of what might affect the exec status. Whether or not a file has been correctly deleted, has no influence on the exit status of the `find` command, because the only way an error in deletion of a file is communicated, is the exit code of `rm`, and the exit code of the executed program is ignored. You can verify this easily by trying, for example,

```
find . -type f -prune -exec false \;
```

If you check the exit code of *find* here, it will be 0, although (by construction) every executed command returns a non-zero exit state.

In your case, the problem comes from your usage of `-rf`. Doing this, you already remove a whole directory tree first, and then ask *find* to present the files to the command in the "-exec". Using the `-depth` option makes *find* using a depth-first search and you don't have the problem.

Note also that with your approach, you do not check the creation time of the directory, but the modification time. This is just for clarification - maybe this is what you want, in particular since you can't get the directory creation time anyway.

Another question is, whether you really want to traverse the directory tree, or whether it is maybe sufficient to just traverse the top-level directories. With other words, if you have directories `./top1/bootom1` and `.top2/bottom2`, and top1 and bottom2 have been modified yesterday, but top2 and bottom1 have not been modified for weeks, do you really want to be removed `bottom1` (leaving the rest of top1 intact) and `top2` (including its subdirectory)? You current approach would do this, and if this is, what you want, it is of course the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for adding more details about the possible cause of the problem. Yes we kind of overcoming the problem using `-depth`. In my case folder `\some\thing` is the base folder and inside this there will be multiple folders. Data comes into these folders once and we won't modify or touch these folders and files present in them. so every day a new folder will be added and each folder contains only one file. So we haven't had any problems in the deletion of the folders as per modified time